# Cell Splitter for Twitter Bootstrap Grid System

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-directive

I have a bootstrap grid with one row and two columns, now I want set splitter between those columns.
My code looks like this.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
        <!--need to work here-->
        <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to create an angular directive or bootstrap splitter that will split those two columns. This example is similar to Silverlight. How can i create that splitter? Do you have any knowledge? Thanks everybody who has read my write.

Comment: What do you mean by "splitter"?

Comment: @Skelly I think he wants something like http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxsplitter/jquery-splitter-getting-started.htm But for BT....

Comment: @TheLittlePig, you are right, I am looking this type of solution.

Comment: What about responsiveness? How do you expect it to behave on smaller screens which will show the 2 columns not in one row? Also, do you want it to be draggable like in the jQuery example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create **splitter** manually. See this [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Bek9L/1779/) or [Plnlkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/SLR2sKCHQcba9YXZIetn?p=preview).

**EDIT**

You will try by this following code
**HTML**

```
<div id="sidebar">
   <span id="position"></span>
   <div id="dragbar"></div>
   sidebar
</div>
<div id="main">
   main
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body,html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#main {
    background-color: BurlyWood;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    right: 0;
    left: 200px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#sidebar {
    background-color: IndianRed;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

#dragbar {
    background-color: black;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    width: 3px;
    cursor: col-resize;
}

#ghostbar {
    width: 3px;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: col-resize;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 0;
    var dragging = false;
    $('#dragbar').mousedown(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        dragging = true;
        var main = $('#main');
        var ghostbar = $('<div>', {
            id: 'ghostbar',
            css: {
                height: main.outerHeight(),
                top: main.offset().top,
                left: main.offset().left
            }
        }).appendTo('body');
        $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
            ghostbar.css("left", e.pageX + 2);
        });
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        if (dragging) {
            $('#sidebar').css("width", e.pageX + 2);
            $('#main').css("left", e.pageX + 2);
            $('#ghostbar').remove();
            $(document).unbind('mousemove');
            dragging = false;
        }
    });
});
```

This is the more comprehensive [example](http://methvin.com/splitter/vsplitter.html) for div splitter.